# Gatling with karate performance testing is open source?

Tags: karate

I am planning to use Gatling with karate for performance testing if it works.I have a question before using it.

is Gatling open source? I checked the website they have some pricing. not sure they have made it paid tool.

Comment: See https://gatling.io/open-source/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here is the project on GitHub: https://github.com/gatling/gatling